# Find and replace a specific heading with another in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to replace a heading (*ex.Heading 1*) with another heading with different styles. I tried [Find and Replace Formatting in Microsoft Word](http://lifehacker.com/351144/find-and-replace-formatting-in-microsoft-word), and replaced the desire style into another style I wanted.

But the problem is the changed style still keep its latest heading name. (*heading 1*)

I want a way to be able to find all the instance of a specific heading and replace it by another.

Answer (score 3):

So I found a way to [Change all instances of a style at once with Word's Formatting And Styles pane](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/change-all-instances-of-a-style-at-once-with-words-formatting-and-styles-pane/)

> 1. Select the first section heading.
> 2. Go to View | Task Pane; click the drop-down arrow at the top of the
>      pane, and select Styles And Formatting. (In Word 2007, click the
>      dialog launcher box in the Styles group of the Home tab.)
> 3. Right-click the highlighted style for the selection (in this
>      example, Heading 1 is highlighted.)
> 4. Click Select All xx Instance(s). In this example, there are three
>      instances of this style
>
> Word selects all instances of the Heading 1 style throughout the
>   document. You see that all three instances are applied to your section
>   headings, and you would like to change the style to Heading 2. To
>   change all three instances, click Heading 2 in the Task Pane